# Create reports/queries via a GUI that respect database relations (replace Oracle Discoverer)

Tags: database, gui, reporting

I am looking for a tool to replace Oracle Discoverer. The main goal is to support non-technical users in their reporting. Despite other functionalities, the main ones are as follows:

1. The must-have feature is the building of queries via a GUI that respects database relations.

   - It is minimally required that the user gets a notification that the join is not possible.
   - Ideally would be that it supports the actual options for joining
2. The software is a layer on top of the DB that allows the setup of (additional) relations between objects in the database which are not related
3. Ideally the software should be able to define access rights for user group

Any suggestions or experiences?

Answer (score 0):

The non-programmers at my office do really well with [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.com/).

Comment: Can you go a bit more into details on how Beaver meets the requirements? Does it fit all of them, or just mostly? Also, how much does it cost?